# Java Sockets and proxy

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

Now i try to do program, which work with proxy servers. Request from browser sent to localhost:8080, where my program get it. And i want to send this request to proxy server and get response from it and then show it in browser.

I create server socket.

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);           
    while (true) {
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.err.println("Client accepted");
        new Thread(new SocketProcessor(s)).start();
    }
```

SocketProcessor constructor

```
public SocketProcessor(Socket s) throws Throwable {
    this.s = s;
    this.is = s.getInputStream();
    this.os = s.getOutputStream();
}
```

Then i read the request:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));      
    while(true) {           
        String s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);              
        if(s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

And it seems like:

```
//http
GET http://www.google.ru/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.ru
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Data: CJW2yQEIprbJAQiptskB
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie:24602526:LM=1424608005:S=URlBDO1T8eYEA5M4;
//https
CONNECT www.google.ru:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.ru
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
```

I tried to print String s to socket.getOutputStream() bu PrintWriter, but server always response error 404, and after write this response in browser socket, it doesnt show anything.

Try to write response in this code:

```
BufferedReader bred = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String t="";
    String res = "";
    while((t = bred.readLine()) != null){
        res=res+t;          
    }
    os.write(res.getBytes());
    os.flush();
```

What can you advice me something?